# List and Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface below:

```
/**
 * <T> Time format. Can be long, date etc
 */
public interface TimeStamp<T> extends Comparable<TimeStamp<T>>
{
/**
 * Returns the timestamp. 
 * @return 
 */
public T getTimeStamp();
}
```

Now I want to have a list, that will hold TimeStamp and have some methods whose behavior will depend upon the timeStamps it holds.

```
public class TimeList<TimeStamp<T>> extends ArrayList<TimeStamp<T>> 
{
     ......
}
```

The compiler shows error with the above statement. What is wrong with it?

Comment: *"The compiler shows error with the above statement."* => What error?

Comment: FYI it is bad practice to extend `ArrayList` because it is not designed for subclassing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the class definition you can only specify the generic type alone, try:

```
public class TimeList<T> extends ArrayList<TimeStamp<T>> 
{
 ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I used composition. SO instead of extending, I want to hold a list of tiemstamps. What should be the code then?

Comment: pre java 7: `List<TimeStamp<YourType>> list = new LinkedList<TimeStamp<YourType>>();`, java 7 :  `List<TimeStamp<YourType>> list = new LinkedList<>();`